# Let $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n>0$, $x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n =1$ then $\sum_{i<j}x_{i}x_{j}\ge \binom{n}{2}$

Tags: inequality

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem:

Q: Let $x_1,x_2,\cdots,x_n>0: x_1 x_2 \cdots x_n =1$
Prove that:
$$\sum_{i<j}x_{i}x_{j}\ge \binom{n}{2}$$

My study

Using the arithmetic geometric mean, only the inequality
$$x_1+x_2+x_3+\cdots+ x_n \ge n$$
can be derived. I don't know of any other approach. Obviously you are using arithmetic geometric mean, but how should I approach it?

Comment: Directly applying AM-GM inequality, $$\frac{\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j}{\binom n2} \ge \sqrt[\binom n2]{x_1^{n-1}x_2^{n-1}\cdots x_n^{n-1}}$$

Comment: Ok thank you It's fixed right away

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Directly applying AM-GM inequality,
$$\begin{align*}
\frac{\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j}{\binom n2} &\ge \sqrt[\binom n2]{x_1^{n-1}x_2^{n-1}\cdots x_n^{n-1}} = 1\\
\sum_{i<j}x_ix_j &\ge \binom n2
\end{align*}$$